# "How should such an application of results from mathematical models, as presented in this paper, look like?"

Tags: prepositions

Is the above sentence correct?

In particular, is it OK to put the "like" at the end or is there a better option?
Moreover, should it be "... of results of mathematical models ..."? In my opinion, "of results from" sounds better as there is only one "of", but I am not sure whether it is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: You can't really say "How should such an application of results ... look like". That doesn't make sense. What does "application of results" even mean? Could you tell us, in simple terms, what you are trying to say.

Comment: No, you can't include the word "like" in your context. We ask ***What** does it look **like**?*, or ***How** does it **look**?*

Comment: What does such an application look like?

Comment: @Peter4075 I want to say something like: Which form should such an application take? For instance, you could use the results straightaway in management decisions or you could use the results to set up new experiments for confirmation,...

Comment: Advice: How should X look? Lose: like

Answer (score 1):

“How should such an application of results from mathematical models, as presented in this paper, look like?” is ungrammatical. You can write either...

“"What should such an application of results from mathematical models, as presented in this paper, look like?” or...

“How should such an application of results from mathematical models, as presented in this paper, look?”

They both mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other place for "like" as the verb has to be at the end ([ref;](https://www.espressoenglish.net/an-easy-way-to-form-almost-any-question-in-english/)) and "like" is what turns "look" into a linking verb.

The unease you experience is due to the relative length of your question; these questions can't be too long. When the terms used make the question too long, the best is to split your question into two parts, one part for the presentation of the term and another for the short question iself; this is effected at the price of a little repetition only.

- My concern is an application of results from mathematical models, as presented in this paper; what¹ should such an application look like?

"From" appears more proper than "of", I agree with that.

¹<sub>Correction after this [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers); as is mentioned, "how" shouldn't be used here; "what" is the word that is always used.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

An introductory sentence might be:

> What are the applications of the mathematical modelling of XYZ
>   discussed in this paper?

Where XYZ is the thing being modelled. You could then go on to discuss these applications.

If you're looking for a heading to summarise your discussion of applications, you could try:

> Mathematical modelling of XYZ - applications